# CSS Grid - Span Cols and Rows?

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to acheive the following layout using a CSS Grid.

[image]

Is it a Grid with 8 columns and 3 rows where the first larger content (an image) spans three columns and 3 rows or do I size the first column to be a higher Fractional Unit (FR) that the second and third columns?

Does the same solution work for the final "column" of text and basket UX?

Comment: Please add your code what your have tried so far.

Comment: Fairp point although I am creating it in WebFlow CMS as I need to hand it over to non developers after and the code it spits out is pretty nasty IMHO. I'll have a go at creating it outside of WebFlow and come back with my work in progress

Comment: How accurate do you have to be? Does it matter if the proportions aren't exactly as in the image?

Comment: It does not matter. The eventual solution also needs to work on mobile so I'm going to need to play about with the sizes there too